# Ruby displaying newline on attribute call

Tags: ruby

I am writing a BlackJack game to start my learning of Ruby (so I'm pretty new) and for the player class I wanted to put a name parameter in the initialize method so that the game can call the player by name.  This all works fine but when I use @player.name to get the name it is adding a newline after the name.  Instead of:

```
Billy's hand is:
```

I get:

```
Billy
's hand is:
```

I tried fiddling with puts and print but nothing seems to work.  It seems like an easy fix for someone who knows Ruby but I'm just not experienced enough and it's hard to word for a Google search.  Here is my code:

```
require 'Hand'

class Player

  attr_accessor :hand, :cash, :name

  def initialize(n)
     @hand = Hand.new
     @cash = 500
     @name = n
  end

end

require 'Player'

class Game

    puts "What is your name? "
    name = gets

    @deck = Deck.new
    @player = Player.new(name)
    .
    .
    .
 def self.showHands(num)
    puts @player.name + "'s hand: "
    .
    .
    .
```

Furthermore, when I initialize the Player object without using the puts/gets methods like this:

```
@player = Player.new("Billy")
```

the String works exactly how I want it to.  I am using Ruby 1.9.3.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: replace `gets` with `gets.chomp` to remove the newline.

Comment: Yes, Ruby is incredible.  One day you will discover things about it that are even more amazing than `chomp`.

Comment: I think if you just put `p "What is your name?"` it doesn't include the newline.

Comment: @Matt Is there any reason `gets.chomp` would be preferred over `gets.strip`?

Comment: In this case, I don't think it makes too much of a difference. It's the specificity of `chomp` that also communicates that one is specifically removing a newline, so its intent is clear. If you're concerned that someone may introduce unnecessary whitespace around the input, then by all means use `strip`.